# how to remove object if all values are empty in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multiple objects in array. It has values array with value property in object. when all value properties are empty. I want to remove whole object.

I tried it but i am not able to produce output.
Please help me.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "field": "surname",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "given names",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "date of birth",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "25.07.1974",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "05 JUN /JOIN 57",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  }
];

 for (let x = data.length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
            let count = 1;
            var dataValueLength = data[x].values.length;
            for (let y = 0; y < data[x].values.length; y++) {
                if (data[x].values[y].value === "") {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (dataValueLength == count) {
                data.splice(x, 1)
            }
        }
        
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

In above scenario, output should be only one object that is "date of birth".

Comment: where in the given data is one object empty? please add an example of what to test and what to delete.

Comment: Are you talking about `"values": []` or where all `values.value = ""` ? Or what of the two?

Comment: I am looking for values.value == ""

Comment: What if `date of birth` had a third item in values array that had a `value` property of an empty string? Would you want the `date of birth` object have only 2 items in values or 3?

Answer (score 4):

**Very close**, just one issue (you are initializing `count` to `1` instead of `0`), make it

```
let count = 0;
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [{
    "field": "surname",
    "values": [{
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "given names",
    "values": [{
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "date of birth",
    "values": [{
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "25.07.1974",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "05 JUN /JOIN 57",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  }
];

for (let x = data.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
  let count = 0; //Observe change in this line 
  var dataValueLength = data[x].values.length;
  for (let y = 0; y < data[x].values.length; y++) {
    if (data[x].values[y].value === "") {
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (dataValueLength == count) {
    data.splice(x, 1)
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to filter out the items with no `values`

```js
var data = [
  {
    "field": "surname",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "given names",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "date of birth",
    "values": [     
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  }
];

var result = data.reduce(function(p,c){
    if(c.values && c.values.length > 0)
        p.push(c);
    return p;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use `filter()`:

```
 var filtered = data.filter(item => item.values.some(v => v.value))
```

This will return an array removing items where the all `values.value`s are false(y).

```js
var data = [
  {
    "field": "surname",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "given names",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "date of birth",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "25.07.1974",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "05 JUN /JOIN 57",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  }
];

var filtered = data.filter(item => item.values.some(v => v.value))
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.every`

- `filter` creates a new array of all element for which the supplied lambda returns True
- `every` determines if every element in an array returns True for the supplied lambda

So we want to *filter* objects where *every* `value` (in the `values` array) is not equal to an empty string

```
const data1 = 
  data.filter (o =>
    o.values.every (v => v.value !== ''))
```

Full demo

```js
const data0 = [
  {
    "field": "surname",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "given names",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "date of birth",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "25.07.1974",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "05 JUN /JOIN 57",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  }
];

const data1 = 
  data0.filter (f =>
    f.values.every (v => v.value !== ''))
    
console.log (data1)
// [
//   {
//     "field": "date of birth",
//     "values": [
//       {
//         "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
//         "value": "25.07.1974",
//         "isAvailable": true
//       },
//       {
//         "id": "passport",
//         "value": "05 JUN /JOIN 57",
//         "isAvailable": true
//       }
//     ],
//     "status": "passed"
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Start count from 0 and count it correctly :)

https://jsfiddle.net/vLLs4px5/

```
var data = [
  {
    "field": "surname",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "given names",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "date of birth",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "25.07.1974",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "05 JUN /JOIN 57",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  }
];

 for (let x = data.length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
            var count = 0;
            var dataValueLength = data[x].values.length;
            for (let y = 0; y < data[x].values.length; y++) {
                if (data[x].values[y].value == "") {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
            if (dataValueLength == count) {
                data.splice(x, 1)
            }
        }

        console.log((data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach`

```
let counter = 0;
data.forEach(function(el) {
    let isEmpty = true;
    let element = el.values
    element.forEach(function(e)) {
        if (e.value != "") {
            isEmpty = false;
        }
    });
    if (!isEmpty) {
        data.splice(counter, 1);
    }
    counter++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need this code not to crash on unexpected input or remove any values item that has a falsy value property you can try this:

```
var data = [
  null,
  undefined,
  {},
  {values:"hello world"},
  {
    "field": "surname",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "given names",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "field": "date of birth",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "drivingLicenseFront",
        "value": "25.07.1974",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "passport",
        "value": "05 JUN /JOIN 57",
        "isAvailable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "this is gone",
        "value": "",
        "isAvailable": true
      }
    ],
    "status": "passed"
  }
];

data.map(
  data=>
    Object.assign(
      {},
      (data||{}),
      {
        values:Array.from((data&&data.values)||[])
          .filter(
            value=>
              (value&&value.value)
          )
      }
    )
)
.filter(
  data=>
    data.values.length!==0
)
```